# Differences between backtracking and brute-force search

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, backtracking

I'm currently taking a course in algorithms, and I'm having some difficulty understanding the exact definitions of brute-force search and backtracking. As I understand it, the following is true:

- *Brute-force search* (*BFS*) is a type of algorithm which computes every possible solution to a problem and then selects one that fulfills the requirements.
- *Explicit* constraints give the possible values for each choice (e.g., choices 1-3 are limited to `{1, 2}`, choice 4 is limited to `{3, 4, 5}`, etc.), which determines how the search's "execution tree" is shaped.
- *Implicit* constraints relate the different choices to eachother (e.g., choice 2 must be greater than choice 1, etc.), which is used in BFS to remove potential solutions.
- *Backtracking* is an extension to BFS in which the *implicit* constraints are evaluated after every choice (as opposed to *after* all solutions have been generated), which means that potential solutions can be discarded before they have been 'finished'.

Basically, all I'm wondering is whether this is accurate or not, and, if it isn't, I'd really appreciate some clarification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Short answer**: If I read the question correctly, you are **correct**.

Well like you say ***explicit constraints*** are constraints on the *domain* of each variable so *x<sub>i</sub>∈S<sub>i</sub>*. Note that *S<sub>i</sub>* does not have to be stated as a collection. You could for instance state that *S<sub>0</sub>* is the set of all prime numbers less than 25.

***Implicit constraints*** on the other hand, are predicates that are defined over *two or more variables* *P(x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>)*. For instance *x<sub>2</sub><x<sub>3</sub>*. But it can also be defined over more variables (for example three).

***Brute force search*** only takes the *explicit* constraints into account: it assigns all possible values from *S<sub>i</sub>* to a variable *x<sub>i</sub>* and this for *all* variables. After it has constructed such a *configuration*, it verifies that all *implicit constraints are satisfied*.

***Backtracking*** on the other hand aims to optimize this process. From the moment that all variables over which an *implicit constraint* is defined are assigned, it verifies that constraint. If the constraint fails, then it immediately assigns a different value to one of the variables. The advantage is that if for instance brute force has assigned 2 to *x<sub>1</sub>=2* and 5 to *x<sub>2</sub>=5*, and the implicit constraint *x<sub>1</sub> > x<sub>2</sub>* fails, then it will not assign values to *x<sub>3</sub>,x<sub>4</sub>,...* only to find out that for all configurations for these values it fail.

Of course there is some bookkeeping involved in backtracking: you need to find out which constraints "fire" when a certain value is set. But for a lot of *constraint programming* problems (like for instance SAT), there exists efficient algorithms to do that (with *watched literals*, etc.). Furthermore constraint programming libraries like *Gecode* also have advanced queuing mechanisms such that fast constraints are evaluated first, etc.

Comment: That's essentially what I meant; thanks! (I can't upvote you because I have less than 15 reputation, but I'll mark your answer as accepted.)

Comment: What is xi and Si? Can you elaborate please?

Comment: @theprogrammer: xi are the variables for which we search for a solution, and Si is the domain (the set of values that variable xi can take).